# Get ID of div created by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two functions, where the first creates a div in the dom and the second gets the ID via `getElementById()`. Unfortunately, my second function is just returning null.

I looked in using `$.Deffered()` in either of my functions, but alas nothing I do seems to work

```
function one() {
    var dynamicDiv = $("<div>").attr("id", 'test');
    dynamicDiv.iziModal({
        //modal content here
    })
}

function two() {
    var container = document.getElementById('test');
    console.log(container.innerHTML); //not returning any data

}


enter code here
```

I had hoped to use this with a library that replaces images with a canvas object, but it requires that the "parent element to be a valid DOM Element". I have been searching for a while now, but I can not seem to find anything on the subject that is applicable.

** Edit**
Thank you for pointing out the error in my id (I had tried something else before I pasted). The iziModal function (http://izimodal.marcelodolza.com/) is currently pulling the content in via ajax (which I assume is the problem here):

The iziModal Function:

```
dynamicDiv.iziModal({
        title: '',
        autoOpen: 1,
        width: 500,
        onOpening: function (offer) {
            offer.startLoading();
            $.get(demoUrl, function (data) {
                $('#' + id + " .iziModal-content").html(data);
                offer.stopLoading();
            });
        }
    });
```

Content of the other file:

```
<div id="test">
    <img src="./bundle/images/coupon.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: Post your HTML please. We need a [mcve]

Comment: The first one is setting `id=test`, but the second is looking for `id=container`.

Comment: The first function never appends the DIV to the DOM, unless that's something that `iziModal()` does.

Comment: Shouldn't you `append` your dynamicDiv somwhere in the DOM before looking for it?
https://api.jquery.com/append/

Answer (score 0):

```
function one() {
    var dynamicDiv = $("<div>").attr("id", 'test');
    dynamicDiv.iziModal({
        //modal content here
    });
    $("body").append(dynamicDiv);
}
```